# Overriding default img css

Tags: css

How can i override img css for particular image.

Let say ,

i have css in my website like

```
img{
border:2px solid #ECECEC;
padding:4px;
}
```

i have one img with in the website say `<img id="example" src="../example.png"/>`

Now , i don't want to apply img css to this particular image.

How can i do that?

Thank

Answer (score 2):

use the `id` as a selector and change the css properties you want.

```
#example{
  border:0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img#example {border:none !important; }
```

No border for image with example id

Comment: no need to use `!important` as the id selector has higher specificity than that tag selector.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't touch the markup, you could use an attribute selector.

```
img[src="../example.png"] {
  border:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: It would be a worst case scenario usage. But now that I think about it... The best way to do it would be @Gaby's way. Because ID's are supposed to be unique per page.

Answer (score 0):

add a separate class to the image 
Example

```
 <img class="example" id="example" src="../example.png"/>
.example{
    border:0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this example:
Give it an inline style, mine worked very simply

Comment: <img src="dot.png" style="width:2%;">